# How to define a custom iterator in C++

Tags: c++, iterator

I've seen a number of posts on SO about how to define custom iterators, but nothing that seems to exactly answers my question, which is...

How do I create an iterator that hides a nested for loop?

For instance, I have a class Foo, inside of the Foo is a Bar, and inside of the Bar is a string. I could write

```
for (const Foo& foo : foo_set)
  for (const Bar& bar : foo.bar_set)
    if (bar.my_string != "baz")
      cout << bar.my_string << endl;
```

but instead I want to be able to do something like:

```
for (const string& good : foo_set)
  cout << good << endl;
```

How do I do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been [proposals](http://lafstern.org/matt/segmented.pdf) and discussion about [segmented iterators](http://stlab.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Segmented_Iterators), but none has actually made it into the C++ standard (yet, anyway).

As it stands right now, about the cleanest way to deal with it (IMO, anyway) is as a collection of items, each of which is itself a collection:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, bar const &b) { 
     return os << b.my_string;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, foo const &f) { 
     std::remove_copy_if(f.begin(), f.end(), 
                         std::ostream_iterator<bar>(os, "\n"),
                         [](bar const &b) { return b.my_string != "baz"; });

     return os;
}

std::copy(foo_set.begin(), foo_set.end(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<foo>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Or, if you insist:

```
for (auto s : foo_set)
    std::cout << s << "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. Although, your example isn't exactly what I was hoping for, since the block on your `for` loop is still iterating over `foo`s; you've just made `<< foo` do the same thing as `<<`ing every `bar` inside the `foo`. Instead, my code block is more complex (I'm not actually `cout`ing) so I need the inner `bar` available in the `for`'s code block. I have no equivalent to `ostream_iterator` :'(

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

What, you want more details?

This should help lots:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html#iterator-facade-and-adaptor

Or:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html#usage
(function input iterator might also work well).

You work on ranges.  The internal state of an iterator is a tuple of inner iterator, outer iterator, and a flag saying if you are at the end.  Increment advances the inner iterator, checks if it equals end on an inner range, and if so advances the outer iterator until it hits the end of the outer range or a non-empty inner range (then sets the inner iterator to the begin of the outer iterator, if the outer iterator is not end!)

Dereference just dereferences an inner iterator.  Blindly!  (well, throw some asserts in)

Equality checks for the outer iterator being equal, and if so checks if the "end flag" is set.  If not, it compares inner iterators being equal.  (Is there an elegant way to avoid that end flag?)

Getting the first element consists of finding an iterator to the first non-empty inner range.

Decrement is a bit tricky, but not required for your task.

Some care has to be taken to avoid having an invalid inner iterator while the outer iterator is valid.  I think I listed most of the gotchas above.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use boost :/

Comment: Yup. That's why I started searching google/SO, and when I couldn't find what I needed, that's what motivated me to post here :)

Comment: The steps are relatively simple.  Have you written an iterator before?  Start with a simple one, like one that returns capital letters from a vector of char.  This is a project in itself.  Then if you want that for loop syntax, you will want to return a struct that is a range and that the for loop syntax understands - that is a third project.